# HttpClient get status code

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Using Apache HttpClient 4.1.3 and trying to get the status code from an `HttpGet`:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet response = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String body = client.execute(response, handler);
```

**How do I extract the status code (202, 404, etc.) from the `body`?** Or, if there's another way to do this in 4.1.3, what is it?

Also, I assume a perfect/good HTTP response is an `HttpStatus.SC_ACCEPTED` but would like confirmation on that as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try with:

```
HttpResponse httpResp = client.execute(response);
int code = httpResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The HttpStatus should be 200 ( `HttpStatus.SC_OK` )

(I've read too fast the problem!)

---

Try with:

```
GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("http://www.example.com");
int res = client.executeMethod(getMethod);
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Enrichman - thank you but it doesn't look like `GetMethod` exists in 4.1.3 - any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

// Status Code
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
// Response Body
String responseBody = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
```

Answer (score 4):

I do it like:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

To get the respose body as a String though by not using a responseHandler I get it first as InputStream:

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

and then convert it to a String (ways how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string))